# Clion как автоматически делать комит после каждого запуска программы?

Tags: c++, git, clion

Хочу сконфигурировать среду так, чтобы когда я успешно компилирую программу и запускаю её просто или в режиме дебага, то сохранялась бы локальная копия кода в системе контроля версий.

Comment: так clion и так хранит историю локальных изменений. или Вы прям хотите коммитить (как по мне, то это перебор)

Comment: По моему, в Clion в проекте есть такие штуки как "pre-build script" и "post-build script". Если в pre-build добавить git add -u; git commit -m "regular commit" - вполне возможно, это будет то, что Вам нужно